# jquery navigating to a child tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

In my UI, i have 5 jquery parent tabs.
In the 1st tab(home), I have quick links button that should navigate to other parent tabs. i have used

```
<input type="button" name="addUser" class="BTN"
                value="Add User"
                onclick="$('#maintabs').tabs('select',1);">
```

This navigates to the second tab(Users) in my UI. In Users tab, I have two child tabs-subscribed user and guest user.

when i navigate to the guest user and go back to the home page, again click on the quick link button, it shows the last accessed tab in the Users tab.

Now, if i always want to navigate to the first child(subscribed users) in this user tab, Is there any way to set the focus to the first child tab?

Answer (score 0):

Use the the `show` option when you define the tabs on the parent tab group:

```
$('#maintabs').tabs({
     show: function(e, ui) {
         if (ui.index == 1) { // the index of the "Users" tab
             // select the first tab in Users child tab group
             // (replace "#usertabs" by the accurate selector)
             $('#usertabs').tabs('select', 0);
         }
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

index of first tab is always 0 .so check that by changing index